# How to create a circular stream?

Tags: scala, scalaz, scalaz-stream

I'm trying to create a circular process using scalaz-stream by merging one source of data with a filtered version coming from the same data source. Here is a simple example of what I have so far :

```scala
val s1 = Process.emitAll(1 to 10).toSource

val w = wye.merge[Int]

val s2 = w.filter(_ < 5)

val w2 = s1.wye(s2)(w)
```

But it doesn't compile as `s2` is a `Process[Process.Env[Int,Int]#Y,Int]` but needs to be a `Process[Task,Int]`.

How can I specify that s2 is both the input (with `s1`) and the output of `w`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this answer on the scalaz-mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scalaz/tEFqyuCAepk) Short answer is it's not possible to do exactly what you are asking, but there are often other ways of phrasing your problem.

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is in st2 that is defined like zipping wye (w) with t2. This does nt make a sense hence wye is just description how the processes will be merged.

I think t2 is Process[Task,Duration] so you will need on left side another Process[Task,Duration] and then you can use wye.merge[Duration] to merge them together like:

```
val t1: Process[Task,Duration] = ???
val t2: Process[Task,Duration] = Process.awakeEvery(3 second)

val st2: Process[Task.Duration] = t1.filter(_ < 5 seconds).zip(t2).map(_._1)
val w2: Process[Task.Duration] = t1.wye(st2)(wye.merge) //or simply t1.merge(t2)
```

Maybe type anotations on every line will guide your path.

Comment: Pavel, I added the `Duration` events to time my `Int` events (those are the one I care about). I simplified the code example and clarified the question: how can I specify that s2 is both the input and the output of `w`?